# Upload a new page to a Wordpress website using Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wordpress

I need to create a Ruby on Rails application that can upload a new html page to a Wordpress website.

As far as I know, Wordpress stores their pages in DB.

I don't know where to start, please show me a way, or an example would be nice too.

Answer (score 0):

First Thing First,

Ruby on Rails application can upload html but wordpress is CMS. So, it dynamically adds pages so, there is possible that may be no static pages in site.

Second Thing for wordpress,

Wordpress uses mysql database for storing their pages. so, you don't need to send whole page html just supply page content and wordpress can automatically add in. WordPress come with variety of functionality for Dynamics. e.g., CLI, REST-API.

For Ruby On Rails you could use any of one. from cli you can add dynamic pages. function for add page as below:

```
$custom_posts = array(
        'post_type'     => 'page',
        'post_title'    => wp_strip_all_tags($post_title ),
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
        'post_author'   => 1,
    );

    // Insert the post into the database
    wp_insert_post( $custom_posts );
```